# How to compute custom id to grow to infinity

Tags: t-sql

I have a user define function as below, to compute a custom Id using PK Id as guide

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CustomeId] (
 @Prefix NVARCHAR(10),
 @Id INT,
 @Length INT,
 @PaddingChar CHAR(1) = '0'
 )
 RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 AS
 BEGIN

 RETURN (
 SELECT @Prefix + RIGHT(REPLICATE(@PaddingChar, @Length) + CAST(@Id as     nvarchar(10)), @Length)
 )

 END
```

In my sql table's Computed Column specification I have:

```
 ([dbo].[CustomeZoneId]('GH-',CONVERT([nvarchar](10),[Id],(0)),(10),'0'))
```

and out put is as below:

```
 GH-0000000001 , GH-999999999, etc
```

but I want it to be able to grow to infinity along side the PK Id. something like:

```
GH-9, GH-99, GH-999 to infinity
```

Comment: And what have this to do with c#?

Comment: No numeric data type can hold value upto infinity. Is it real time scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to C# but to SQL Server.

To Answer your question, there is not such datatype which can grow to infinity, however if you want the max you can user

```
nvarchar[max]
```

hope this helps..

Comment: What I mean is not size of data but number, for eg, say 1 to 1 billion and still counting without end as long as the table ID column is growing.